# Which script will run for creation of icons like Lock Screen, Log Out, Power Off, Suspend, Switch User from GNOME Dash?

Tags: 20.04

When I searched for restart application I got power off icon instead of restart in dashboard, where can I do changes for the remove restart script from power off icon?

Restart
[image: restart]

Comment: Make a right mouse click onto and select details.

Comment: When you click that poweroff icon, are you getting option to choose restart??

Comment: Not sure, but it may help to ask us about your real problem. Not about how you think you can solve it.

Comment: @paladin Right click not working for that application

Comment: @UnKNOWn yaa, when i click in dialog box i can see cancel, restart and power off options, but how i can get restart as a separate icon

Comment: 20.04 uses gnome-shell 3.38. it requires source code to be edited which is similar to creating gnome shell extension. When you upgrade to latest versions in future where shell version is 40. You can have that behaviour by default. Do you want to go for extension?

Comment: @UnKNOWn yes, can you please suggest what is that extension

Comment: There is nothing yet. But tweaking this extension can achieve what you are looking for. I don't have shell 3.38 running otherwise would have done ity self.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3246/hide-system-actions/